Is $L^2([a,b]; L^2(S^2))$ the same as $L^2([a,b] \times S^2)$?
The space $L^2([a,b];L^2(S^2))$ is a Banach space with respect to the norm
$$\left\Vert f \right\Vert_1^2 = \int_{a}^b  \left\Vert f(r) \right\Vert_{L^2(S^2)}^2 dr$$
The space $L^2([a,b]\times S^2)$ is a Banach space with respect to the norm
$$\left\Vert f \right\Vert_2^2 = \int_{a}^b \int_{S^2} |f|^2r^2 drd\sigma_{S^2}$$
where $d\sigma_{S^2}$ is the volume form on the unit sphere.
For each function $f \in L^2([a,b];L^2(S^2))$, we can interpret it as a function on $[a,b]\times S^2$ by in the obvious way: $f(r,x) = f(r)(x)$ for $r\in [a,b]$ and $x\in S^2$. This defines a map $\Phi$ from $L^2([a,b];L^2(S^2))$ to $L^2([a,b]\times S^2)$
Are these two spaces the same? Or does one live properly in the other? In other words, is $\Phi$ an isomorphism, or an embedding?
Suppose we pick a function $f$ in $L^2([a,b];H^1(S^2))$. We know that $f(a)$, $f(b)$ are  not well-defined elements in $H^1(S^2)$. Is there a version of the trace theorem stating that $f(a)$,$f(b)$ are well-defined elements in $H^{1/2}(S^2)$?
Please send me any references on this. I didn't find papers or books that study these spaces.

How do you define measureability of a function $[a, b] \to L^2(S^2)$?  Just that the "uncurried" function $[a, b] \times S^2 \to \mathbb C$ is measureable?  Does that notion of measureablity come from an honest $\sigma$-algebra on $L^2(S^2)$?

I think it's the function $r \mapsto \lVert f(r) \rVert_{L^2(S^2)}$ that is measurable. So $f$ is any function on $[a,b]$ taking values in $L^2(S^2)$ with the property that $r \mapsto \lVert f(r) \rVert_{L^2(S^2)}$ is a measurable $L^2$ function from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Yes, the spaces agree with one another and also with $L^2(a,b)\otimes L^2(S^2)$. An easy way to see this is to consider the natural map $L^2((a,b)\times S^2)\to L^2((a,b); L^2(S^2))$ on (say) smooth functions. It is isometric with dense domain and range and thus extends to a unitary map, still acting in the obvious way.

@LSpice Usually when one works with these spaces, what is required is "strong measurability" a.k.a. "Bochner measurability" which is formally stronger; roughly speaking, one takes good approximation by vector-valued simple functions as a definition, rather than a consequence.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67434/computing-bochner-integrals-with-values-in-lp-spaces-by-lebesgue-integrals

@ChristianRemling Is it clear that this natural map is even well-defined? Remember elements of both spaces are equivalence classes with respect to a different relation. Let $f_1,f_2 \in L^2([a,b]\times S^2)$ that agree on a measure $0$ set in $[a.b] \times S^2$. Why would $f_1,f_2$ agree on a measure $0$ set on $[a,b]$ as a map taking $r$ to $\lVert f(r) \rVert_{L^2(S^2)}$?

@Laithy: There is no such issue. I defined the map on smooth functions originally, so there is a unique continuous representative $f(r,\omega)$ that I map to the element of $L^2(a,b; L^2(S^2))$ that is represented by the function $g:(a,b)\to L^2(S^2)$ given by (obviously) $g(r)(\omega)=f(r,\omega)$.

But even for general functions, this is not a problem: I must then show that if $f_1(r,\omega)=f_2(r,\omega)$ a.e. wrt the product measure, then also $g_1(r)=g_2(r)$ for a.e. $r\in (a,b)$, where the equality now takes place in $L^2(S^2)$. In other words, I must show that for a.e. $r$, we have $g_1(r)(\omega)=g_2(r)(\omega)$ for a.e. $\omega\in S^2$, which is an immediate consequence of Fubini.

Oh I see. Thank you :)
If you can answer the second part of the question, I will accept it as an answer.
